# Simpler file type matching in .gitattributes

Tags: git

We're setting up line-ending encoding rules in an existing git repo and realized it was affecting binary files when we didn't want it to.

I can't find any information as to which file-matching patterns are supported in this file. Rather than listing *all* text file extensions we have (or excluding all binary files) is there a way to match files by their type instead?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Check [`man gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: ... However, you could use a pre-commit hook which keeps binary files out of the repo. You can use the `file` command in that hook to detect the file type